# What does the MID mean in this pseudo code?

Tags: pseudocode

this is the picture of the the algorithim, i was just wondering if anyone here knew what they mean by MID() at the bottom and explain what its actually doing.

[image]

Comment: I suppose it is substring, like https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_mid.asp

Answer (score 0):

As Illya said in the comments, MID is a substring function.

So what that code is doing is generating a random number between 1 and 10, if the number is 3 or 6 it will loop and create another random number, probably because the format of the string is either dd/mm/yyyy, mm/dd/yyyy, dd-mm-yyyy etc. where the 3rd and 6th characters are not numeric.

If the random number is not 3 or 6, it will exit the loop and return the character that is at the random position.

Not sure why the While has a condition P>10 as the RANDINT should not return a value greater than 10.